# CMake doesn't generate depend object files

Tags: c++, linker, cmake, build-dependencies

I'm writing a little compiler, but now I'm stuck with cmake, which doesn't generate all depend object files.

Only `main.cpp` is compiled:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lexer.h"
#include "parser.h"

int main() {
    Lexer lexer(&std::cin);
    Parser parser(&lexer);

    parser.binaryOpPrecedence['<'] = 10;
    parser.binaryOpPrecedence['+'] = 20;
    parser.binaryOpPrecedence['-'] = 20;
    parser.binaryOpPrecedence['*'] = 40;

    std::cerr << "ready> ";
    parser.getNextToken();

    parser.parse();

    return 0;
}
```

My `CMakeLists.txt` is the following (subdirectory):

```
set(SOURCE_FILES
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ast/binary.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ast/call.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ast/expression.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ast/function.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ast/number.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ast/prototype.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ast/variable.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/lexer.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/parser.cpp
    PARENT_SCOPE
)

add_executable(kaleidoscope main.cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

As said, only `main.cpp` is compiled to `main.cpp.o` but not `lexer.cpp` and `parser.cpp`, so the linker crashes with unresolved symbols. Don't know, what I've done wrong.

```
/usr/bin/cmake --build /home/patkar/.clion10/system/cmake/generated/d6bd25de/d6bd25de/Debug --target kaleidoscope -- -j 4
Scanning dependencies of target kaleidoscope
[100%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/kaleidoscope.dir/main.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable kaleidoscope
CMakeFiles/kaleidoscope.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Lexer':
/home/patkar/workspace/compiler-fun/kaleidoscope/src/lexer.h:49: undefined reference to `vtable for Lexer'
CMakeFiles/kaleidoscope.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/patkar/workspace/compiler-fun/kaleidoscope/src/main.cpp:36: undefined reference to `Parser::parse()'
CMakeFiles/kaleidoscope.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `~Lexer':
/home/patkar/workspace/compiler-fun/kaleidoscope/src/lexer.h:38: undefined reference to `vtable for Lexer'
/home/patkar/workspace/compiler-fun/kaleidoscope/src/lexer.h:38: undefined reference to `vtable for Lexer'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [src/kaleidoscope] Error 1
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/kaleidoscope.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/kaleidoscope.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [kaleidoscope] Error 2
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `SOURCE_FILES` is set to the correct paths?

Comment: Not directly, but the paths are correct, as I use the `SOURCE_FILES` in the test target too and there it works. And that's it, the `PARENT_SCOPE` made the variable inaccessible/empty in the current scope?

Comment: Yeah, I've encountered this same issue. Unfortunately, the [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html) doesn't provide any specification for this behavior either. You would think that by setting it in the parent scope, it would be accessible in the current scope as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it was the `PARENT_SCOPE` which made my `SOURCE_FILES` variable inaccessible/empty in the current scope :O

I need this for my testing target to access there all the source files. I now created a new variable with `PARENT_SCOPE` as workaround.

```
set(SOURCE_FILES
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ast/binary.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ast/call.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ast/expression.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ast/function.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ast/number.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ast/prototype.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/ast/variable.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/lexer.cpp
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/parser.cpp
)

set(SOURCE_TEST_FILES ${SOURCE_FILES} PARENT_SCOPE)

add_executable(kaleidoscope main.cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: I think you mean `add_executable(kaleidoscope main.cpp ${SOURCE_TEST_FILES})` :P

Comment: No, `add_executable(kaleidoscope main.cpp ${SOURCE_FILES})` is correct. The `SOURCE_TEST_FILES` is the one with `PARENT_SCOPE` to access it in the test executable.